# Get full tree for current category

Tags: mysql, tree, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I've build a MySQL tree using tips on http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ Let's say that my tree looks like:

```
Electronics
--Keyboards
--Phones
----HTC DESIRE Z
----HTC ONE X
-------Camera
-------Battety
Food
--Fruits
----Apple
----Watermelon
--Vegetables
----Carrot
----Onion
```

I can select whole tree or subcategories of any category easly; My problem is that I don't need to select whole tree everytime I browse categories. For example, if I'm in `HTC One X` I dont need to see any of `Food` subnodes. I always want to see all parent of current nodes and all main nodes.

Another example, if I'am in `Phones` i want to see this tree:

```
Electronics
--Keyboards
--Phones
----HTC DESIRE Z
----HTC ONE X
Food
```

For now, I solved it by selecting whole tree and hide unnecessary nodes by CSS. Now my tree have 3k+ rows and it is very slow.

Query that i'm using now:

```
SELECT `node`.`id`,
       (COUNT(parent.id)) AS `depth`,
       `node`.`title`,
       `node`.`link`
FROM `sklep_kategorie` AS `node`
INNER JOIN `sklep_kategorie` AS `parent`
WHERE (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgh)
  AND (node.visible= 1)
GROUP BY `node`.`id_sklep_kategoria`
ORDER BY `node`.`lft` ASC
```

Thank you for any tips

**@edit**
I've did this!
I had to add one field - `parent_id`. With that I'am able to do this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x AS 
SELECT parent.id as parent
FROM `sklep_kategorie` AS `node`
INNER JOIN `sklep_kategorie` AS `parent`
WHERE (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt)
AND (node.id_sklep_kategoria = [ID OF CATEGORY]);

SELECT kat.id_sklep_kategoria, kat.title,kat.link,kat.miniatura
FROM sklep_kategorie kat
LEFT JOIN x
WHERE kat.parent = x.parent
OR kat.parent =0
ORDER BY kat.lft
```